# C# Socket send string conversion

Tags: c#, string, sockets, hex

I'm pretty new to this, so somewhat confused. I want to send "OPTIONS" converted to hex using the Socket class. So here's what I have so far. I have "OPTIONS" converted to hex and want to send "4F5054494F4E53".

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("4F5054494F4E53");
        client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                     new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);

    }
```

But when i set a breakpoint on BeginSend the message byte array contains "52705348" and not "4F5054" etc. How do I deal with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASCII 0x52= char 4, 0x70 = char F etc., 
to get your expected result just:

```
var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("OPTIONS");
```

To verify:

```
        byte[] verifyHex = new byte[] { 0x4F, 0x50,  0x54, 0x49, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x53};
        byte[] verifyDec = new byte[] { 79, 80, 84, 73, 79, 78, 83};

        var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("OPTIONS");

        if (message.Where((t, i) => t != verifyDec[i] || t != verifyHex[i]).Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not equal.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All three representations are equal.");
        }
```

Comment: I just tried that and the array contains 79808473797883 but i need it to have the value stated above.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I'm not sure how will that help me since I would have to convert it again to a byte array and i'd still have the same problem.

Comment: @user1224096: 79 decimal = 0x4F hex = ASCII O, 80 = 0x50 = P, 84 = 0x54 = T, etc.  Google ASCII Table

Comment: @Roger Stewart I get all that, but I don't understand how I am supposed to convert it correctly. I don't want to hardcode the bytes myself, that would be tedious work. I simply want to send "4F5054494F4E53" which is "OPTIONS" converted to hex.

Comment: @user1224096: you stated that you see 79808473797883 when you step through. 79808473797883 is the decimal representation in the debugger. Right-click in the 'Autos' or 'Locals' window when debugging and select 'Hexadecimal display'. This will now show the array contains 4F5054494F4E53.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, thanks again. Have accepted your answer.